# JQuery validate throwing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a validate function using jQuery Validate which is currently giving me the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Yet I can't seem to find out what exactly is wrong with my code. I've tried removing the offending line(s) by commenting them out but all I get is another error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

My Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.extend($.validator.messages,{
            equalTo: "Your passwords do not match.",
            remote: "The password you entered is incorrect."
        });

        $('#PasswordChange').validate(function() {
            rules: {
                ChangePassNew: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6 //<-- the line giving the error.
                },
                ChangePassConfirmNew: { //<-- the line giving the new error once the offending line is commented out
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6
                },
                ChangePassConfirmOld:{
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                    remote: "verifypass.php"
                },
                messages: {
                    ChangePassNew: {
                        required:"Please enter a password.",
                        minlength:"Please enter at least 6 characters."
                    },
                    ChangePassConfirmNew: {
                        required:"Please enter a password.",
                        minlength:"Please enter at least 6 characters."
                    },
                    ChangePassConfirmOld: {
                        required:"Please enter a password.",
                        minlength:"Please enter at least 6 characters.",
                        remote:"The password you entered is incorrect."
                    },
                },
            },
            submitHandler:function(form){
                form.submit();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$('#PasswordChange').validate(function(){
```

to

```
$('#PasswordChange').validate({
```

You need an object holding the options, not a function.